# GPS antenna reference design

Tags: rf, filter, antenna, gps, lna

I have to put a GPS antenna on a PCB layout, but not sure how to calculate a matching network, and how to check that it will work correctly.
I've chosen components with desired features (radiation diagram, amplification, and cost).

Actually, there are two or three networks, antenna - LNA - SAW - output.

But how do you choose the impedance matching components? For example antenna's and LNAs datasheets suggest different inductances. Do I have to put both inductances or choose one that fits?

SAW filter datasheet says that its input and output is 50 Ohm and nothing more. But here in this article *[Adding A GPS Chipset To Your Next Design Is Easy](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/communications/article/21799702/adding-a-gps-chipset-to-your-next-design-is-easy)* they use a capacitor after SAW.

This device in general is a small wearable GPS tracker - gsm+gps.

Components

- [Antenna](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/as/1462350001-AS.pdf)
  [image]
- [Amplifier](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/fc28c774ed2fc26a39a112b212114be16dd4645e/bgu8019.pdf)
  [image]
- [SAW filter](https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/909/AVX_140127_Connectivity-1316412.pdf)
  [image]

Is there some software for network calculation, or maybe some open-source ready schematics?

[image: GPS antenna & amplifier schematic]

Comment: Be clear and unambiguous about the matching network you are talking about. You appear to start talking about matching the antenna but then drift onto the SAW filter. Be clear.

Comment: I’m a newbie in this topic. I’m talking about two networks ( or maybe three!) antenna - lna, lna - saw, saw - output

Comment: What needs matching that you don't understand? Pick one not three. And put inductance values on your schematic - I for one don't want to go looking up some obscure inductor part number. Be specific.

Comment: Try and copy a working reference design or commercial product.  How many have you opened up to see what they did right and wrong? I suggest 5-20.

Answer (score 2):

All of these components are nominally 50 Ohms. For a receiver, improving the impedance match doesn't have a big payoff, so if you're not experienced, you are probably better off putting a DC blocking capacitor between the each stage and moving on.

I'd suggest this, because the LNA may be biased internally in such a way as to have a DC voltage at either the input, the output or both. If you antenna has a DC short, then you'll effectively short out the LNA on the input. On the Output, SAW filters can be sensitive to a DC Bias, so a DC Block could help that last longer. The same on the Output of the SAW/Input to the GNSS chip. The GNSS chip may be able to feed +3V out of the RF port to power a remote antenna, which could cause problems with your SAW.

Comment: Thanks, but here is an unclear thing, does for example antenna’s 50 Ohms Impedance Include the matching network from data sheet? Do I have to use both inductances from antenna’s design as well as from lna’s reference? Or only one of them?

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, neither of those parts are 50Ohm input. That's really annoying.

Comment: So, the datasheet says that the antenna has 50 Ohm Impedance. So maybe inductance is needed for some other reasons?

Comment: The application note you linked seems to imply that the antenna requires the two inductors in a L configuration at C2 and C3 to provide a 50ohm point, so you do have to use those two inductors to provide a 50ohm point looking into the antenna.

Looking at the LNA, it requires a single input matching network consisting of that series inductor, L1, which provides a 50ohm load looking into that series inductor. 

Based on that, I'd suggest you layout a Tee matching configuration, with all three inductors. Do you understand why that is?